# How to call a method from a switch?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a main menu where user is asked to input a digit and for each digit there's a case in a switch statement 
what I am trying to do is that when the user enters a digit that has no case it should return the same menu again

so I created a function containing a switch statement and the default for it is the function itself, however it doesn't work (doesn't display the function again)
what should I do?

```
static void AdminMenu()
{
    char innerchoice;
    Console.WriteLine("Press [1] to Add new student.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [2] to Add new course.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [3] to Enter course prerequisite.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [4] to View List of all students in a specific course.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [5] to View List of Finished courses.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [6] to View List of courses in progress.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [7] to edit all course data.");
    innerchoice = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (innerchoice)
    {
        case '1':    
            break;

        case '2':    
            break;

        case '3':      
            break;

        case '4':       
            break;

        case '5':    
            break;

        case '6':       
            break;

        case '7':    
            break;

        default:
            AdminMenu();


    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn´t work" mean? Any exception? Any unexpected results? Please be more specific on your actual problem.

Comment: Please use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to address the issues in your question.

Comment: `innerchoice = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` seems quirky. Why not `char innerchoice = Console.ReadChar()` or `char innerchoice = Console.ReadLine()[0];`? Also there is no `break;` after the default case, but this doesn't change execution in this code.

Comment: You're missing the `break;` for default.

Comment: I  guess that you are entering a character (not a number) and your program just throwing an exception in this line `char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: it doesnt display the list again @HimBromBeere

Comment: tried both didn't fix anything, the function isn't called again in default case i don't know why @MaximilianGerhardt

Comment: Okay, C# seems to be pickier than what I remembered. The code above does not compile without a `break;` after the `default: AdminMenu();`. With it, it works just fine (confirmed on VS2015)

Comment: I can´t see any problem on this code (despite the missing `break`). However you should not use a recusrive-call for this type of menu, but simply a loop that runs until any of the non-default-branches was executed (indicate this by a `again`-boolean for example).

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt There is no `Console.ReadChar`.

Answer (score 2):

Don´t use recursion to implement a user-menu. It makes your code messy and hard to debug. Simply use any loop and check if it should run again:

```
void PrintMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press [1] to Add new student.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [2] to Add new course.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [3] to Enter course prerequisite.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [4] to View List of all students in a specific course.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [5] to View List of Finished courses.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [6] to View List of courses in progress.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press [7] to edit all course data.");
}

static void AdminMenu()
{
    bool run = true;
    while(run)
    {
        PrintMenu();
        char innerchoice = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (innerchoice)
        {
            case '1':
                run = false;
                break;
            case '2':    
                run = false;
                break;
            case '3':      
                run = false;
                break;
            case '4':       
                run = false;
                break;
            case '5':    
                run = false;
                break;
            case '6':       
                run = false;
                break;
            case '7':    
                run = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why recursion doesnt work?

Comment: @twix As already mentioned in my comment I can´t see anything why it should not work. However it´s hard to tell, as you see. You should debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I added just a break for your default case and it worked for me
[image]

Your default case should be like

```
default:
     AdminMenu();
     break;
```

Comment: but why it doesnt work when i call this function in another one?
http://pastebin.com/Y6VRs4X4

Comment: @twix Can you please be more clear what do you mean by the term another one?

Comment: check the pastebin i mean when i call the adminmenu function in the mainmenu

Comment: @twix I'm not able to access pastebin. Proxy problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must add `break` in the default case otherwise it will through error.

**Try this code :**

```
static void AdminMenu()
{
char innerchoice;
Console.WriteLine("Press [1] to Add new student.");
Console.WriteLine("Press [2] to Add new course.");
Console.WriteLine("Press [3] to Enter course prerequisite.");
Console.WriteLine("Press [4] to View List of all students in a specific course.");
Console.WriteLine("Press [5] to View List of Finished courses.");
Console.WriteLine("Press [6] to View List of courses in progress.");
Console.WriteLine("Press [7] to edit all course data.");
innerchoice = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

switch (innerchoice)
{
    case '1':    
        break;

    case '2':    
        break;

    case '3':      
        break;

    case '4':       
        break;

    case '5':    
        break;

    case '6':       
        break;

    case '7':    
        break;

    default:
        AdminMenu();
        break;// add break in default

}
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: why it doesnt do that when i call the adminmenu function in the mainmenu function?
please check http://pastebin.com/Y6VRs4X4

Comment: The given solution is working fine for me. Properly check your code @twix

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a bool to control if the value is valid and put it on a loop

**Try this code :**

```
    static void AdminMenu()
    {
        char innerchoice;
        bool Leave = false;
        while (Leave == false)
        {
            Leave = true;
            innerchoice = GetChoice();
            switch (innerchoice)
            {
                case '1':
                    break;
                case '2':
                    break;
                case '3':
                    break;
                case '4':
                    break;
                case '5':
                    break;
                case '6':
                    break;
                case '7':
                    break;
                default:
                    Leave = false;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Press a valid value.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static char GetChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press [1] to Add new student.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [2] to Add new course.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [3] to Enter course prerequisite.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [4] to View List of all students in a specific course.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [5] to View List of Finished courses.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [6] to View List of courses in progress.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press [7] to edit all course data.");

        return char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsjp4.png) of what it'll do when pressed an invalid value.